# Angular: Controller não encontra o Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Na minha página principal me mostra o erro: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Insidetv is not defined`, ou seja, o *Controller* não está encontrando o arquivo da *Model*. Porém se eu coloco os dois em um mesmo arquivo funciona perfeitamente.

Na página principal primeiro está chamando o *Model* e depois o *Controller* e ambas as páginas estão sendo encontradas.

Model

```
var Insidetv = angular.module('Insidetv', []);

Insidetv.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
});
```

Controller

```
Insidetv.controller('ListaController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dragStop = function(e, ui) {
        console.log('ok');
    }

    $('.drop').sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        revert: true,
        appendTo: '.lista',
        helper: 'clone',
        stop: $scope.dragStop
    });
});
```

Comment: Se você está colocando o module em um arquivo e o controller em outro você precisa definir o controller dentro de um novo módulo, pois os dois são carregados ao mesmo tempo e a ordem não importa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo [Marcus Dacorrégio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269626/8233), não é recomendado trabalhar desta forma.

O mais correto seria fazer algo assim, cada um em seu arquivo separado:

```
// app.module.js
angular.module('Insidetv', []);

// app.config.js
angular.module('Insidetv')
   .config(function($interpolateProvider){
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
   });

// lista.controller.js
angular.module('Insidetv')
   .controller('ListaController', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.dragStop = function(e, ui) {
         console.log('ok');
      }

      $('.drop').sortable({
         connectWith: "ul",
         revert: true,
         appendTo: '.lista',
         helper: 'clone',
         stop: $scope.dragStop
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser que a sua variável *Insidetv* não tenha sido instanciada antes de criar o seu controller. Tente deixar os arquivos javascript sempre em ordem de carregamento.

Mas de acordo com o styleguide do angular na parte de [modules](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules) você não deve definir uma variável para encapsular o module, e sim usar *chaining*.

> [When using a module, avoid using a variable and instead use chaining with the getter syntax.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#getters)

Dessa maneira você já resolve dois problemas de uma vez só